# Reported speech of future time clauses

Tags: grammar, indirect-speech, backshifting, sequence-of-tenses

How should we report sentences including "***future time clause***?"

> We will have dinner when your father gets home.

Do we have to change the tense of '*future time clause*' or leave it in the original form?:

> My mother said we would have dinner when my father ***got*** home.

OR

> My mother said we would have dinner when my father ***gets*** home.

Comment: Your question involves the topic of **backshift**. There is a related tag on this site: *backshifting*. Some of those posts might be helpful to you. :)

Answer (score 2):

As a native speaker of English, I find both of these sentences grammatically correct, but I would use them in slightly different circumstances. I would use the first when my father had already arrived:

"My mother said we would have dinner when my father **got** home. Well, he's been here since six o'clock and we still haven't had anything to eat!"

I'd use the second if we were still waiting for him:

"My mother said we would have dinner when my father **gets** home. He should be here by six; in the meantime, why don't you have a chocolate bar?"

I make this distinction intuitively, but I would think there are textbooks of English grammar and usage that would support it with formal analysis.